# How do I point the camera in three fiber?

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to point the camera at a location other than the scene origin in Three Fiber, and I'm struggling. I've been using JS for decades, but React is new to me and Three Fiber even more so!

I found this on the web and it works:

```
const PointCam = () => {
  useFrame((state) => {
    state.camera?.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(70, 900, -30))
    state.camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    state.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  });
  return null
}
    
<Canvas camera={{ aspect: 300 / 500, near: 2, far: 50000, fov: 35, position: [-350, 1600, 3150] }} >
  <PointCam />
</Canvas>
```

but I've just discovered that `useFrame` executes every time the scene renders.

How can I execute this just one time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but I had a similar problem. It appears to me that the target property on the camera does not work. However, when I moved the targeting to the orbit control, it worked perfectly.

```
<OrbitControls target={[.6, .4, 0]}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs
https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/hooks

> components that want to participate in the renderloop can use useFrame, components that need to be informed of three.js specifics can use useThree

So you can just replace `useFrame` with `useThree`

```
useThree((state) => {
    state.camera?.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(70, 900, -30))
    state.camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    state.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
});
```